# What’s name of this test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\lim _ { n \rightarrow + \infty } \frac { \ln ( \frac { 1 } { | a _ { n } | } ) } { \ln n } = l$$

1. If $l>1$, the series $a_n$ converges.
2. If $l<1$, the series $a_n$ diverges.
3. If $l=1$, may no conclusion.
   I have known that the **Logarithm’s Test**
   Right or wrong?

Comment: This is a consequence of a comparison test with zeta series, whose con/divergence in turn follows from the integral test. But I don't know that it has any more specific naming than that.

Comment: I think : de Morgan's and Bertrand's test. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BertrandsTest.html

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for Bertrand's test.

Here you can find the convergence tests: [Series Convergence Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests).